# Can't get all files from C:\ directories and subdirectories

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to count all files that exist in C:\ and its subdirectories.
This is what I've tried until now but without success. The function always returns 0.

```
Private Function CountFiles(ByVal Path As String) As Integer
    Dim D As New DirectoryInfo(Path)
    Dim TotalFiles As Integer = 0
    Try
        For Each DD As DirectoryInfo In D.GetDirectories("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            For Each FF As FileInfo In DD.GetFiles("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                TotalFiles += 1
            Next
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return TotalFiles
End Function
```

The strange thing is that I can count files included in another directory (other than C:\ ).

The function stops right before the `For Each DD As DirectoryInfo In D.GetDirectories` line.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many folders on the C: drive are locked and protected by the OS. Probably an exception is raised but you don't show the contente of the ex.Message variable so you can't know what's happening there.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is what I got:
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18 is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run the program as an admin in order to read directories in C drive. Check this [answer by Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16809072/2196341)

Other option would be to goto security and [give full access to username](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Win-7&faq=105) `Everyone`(Not recommended at all)

**UPDATE:**

I was trying this on my system and found out a work around for this without any admin access. I went through debug mode and found some attributes of the directory which were Hidden or system or some windows etc. Using those, I got thisworking on my computer.

```
  Public Function CountFiles(ByVal Path As String) As Integer
        Dim D As New DirectoryInfo(Path)
        Dim TotalFiles As Integer = 0


        For Each DD As DirectoryInfo In D.GetDirectories()
            Dim attrib = Nothing

            If Not IsNothing(DD) Then
                attrib = DD.Attributes
            End If

'Attributes value below indicate they are system directories and cannot be accessed

            If Not (attrib = 22 Or attrib = 9238 Or IsNothing(attrib)) Then
                For Each FF As FileInfo In DD.GetFiles("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    On Error Resume Next
                    TotalFiles += 1
                Next
            End If
        Next


        Return TotalFiles
    End Function
```

Comment: I've already tried running it as an administrator but it's still the same. 
Is there any way to skip restricted directories and continue to the next ones?

Comment: @user2921419 I updated my answer and added a working code. I tried it on my machine and it works fine. I went through debug and got the attirbutes and ignore those dirs.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't get the file count is because your logic is on the try/catch block, and when an access-rights exception occurs the loop breaks, if `TotalFiles` is **0** could be because the first attempt to read the first folder found failed.

You could try my approach below, which is just an approach that avoids accesing to folders that you don't have acces to read.

It uses multi-core improvements.

### **Usage Example**:

```
Dim files As IEnumerable(Of FileInfo) = 
    FileDirSearcher.GetFiles("C:\", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

or:

```
Dim filePaths As IEnumerable(Of String) = 
    FileDirSearcher.GetFilePaths("C:\", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

### **Source**:

**[Filedirsearcher By Elektro](http://pastebin.com/pL6agYA1)**

Note that the source exposes various method overloads that you can use for other needs.