# How can I start processes as administrator?

Tags: vb.net

I can start processes using this command:

```
Process.Start(<My File Location>, <App Parameters>)
```

But how do I start these processes as Administrator?

I tried using this:

```
Process.Start(<My File Location>, "verb -runas")
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run ANOTHER program as Admin \[VB.NET\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804103/run-another-program-as-admin-vb-net)

Comment: It might be more useful to use `ProcessStartInfo`. Have a look at the link. Also it would help to give an idea on what _But too it doesn't work._ actually means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start a Process as administrator mode in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Its not working, :(